# Wordpress WP_Query orderby meta_value_num with unix timestamps

Tags: wordpress, timestamp

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'webcast',
    'meta_key'      => 'webcast-date',
    'meta_value'    => array( time(), strtotime('+60 days') ),
    'meta_type'     => 'numeric',
    'meta_compare'  => 'BETWEEN',
    'orderby '      => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'ASC'
);
$webcasts = new WP_Query($args);
```

I'm using the code above to pull upcoming webcasts onto the homepage. It works fine, except for one anomaly - it's not ordering correctly by date.

The dates are stored as a Unix timestamp, so comparing as number should - I'd have thought - be no problem. However, as an example, the three webcasts that the code below is pulling through at the moment have date values of:

- 1337212800
- 1335225600
- 1338249600

... and that's the order they're displayed in. Even I can see that's not numerically ordered, and my maths is *rubbish*.

So what's going on?

Comment: Ok, just to add - this is the SQL that the code above is generating:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pd_posts.*
FROM pd_posts 
INNER JOIN pd_postmeta ON (pd_posts.ID = pd_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND pd_posts.post_type = 'tsn_webinar'
AND (pd_posts.post_status = 'publish')
AND ( (pd_postmeta.meta_key = 'tsnWebinars-webinar-date' AND CAST(pd_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '1334564263' AND '1339748263') )
GROUP BY pd_posts.ID
ORDER BY pd_posts.post_date
ASC LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: Why use a between? Wouldn't a '>=' (bigger then) be easier?

Comment: I want to fetch webcasts with a date (NB: this is a custom date field, not the post date) greater than the current date, and less than sixty days in the future. Simply using '>=' won't do that. I could use a combination of '>=' AND '<=', but why do all that when there's a perfectly good 'BETWEEN' clause that's designed for the job?

Comment: In the query you can see it orders by `pd_posts.post_date` rather then `pd_postmeta.meta_value`. What happens if you remove the `meta_type` from your array?

Comment: Dunno :) I've now given up on it and am running a SQL query directly with $wpdb->query() instead. I just don't trust WP_Query to do what I tell it to. Thanks though :)

Comment: Okay, to bad I use wp_query in 95%, this can be done with wp_query for sure.